# Incorrect values from MediaQuery.of(context).size in Flutter

Tags: flutter

please help with a problem I have in flutter. I put them in context:

I must create a responsive application. I will use **MediaQuery.of(context).size**, so in my universe I consider:

- size.width > 1280px                 => desktop device
- size.width < 768px                  => mobile device
- size.width between 769px and 1279px => tablet device

1. I create a device in android studio (ADV Manager) with a resolution of 2560px x 1800px (desktop device).

- [device image in ADV Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIbcI.png)

2. I code a simple instruction to know the value of size.width:

- [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcEMN.png)

3. I hope that the console will print the value 2560, but it prints 1280:

- [console results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Xv4.png)

**Note:** I did a lot of tests on all the different types of devices that ADV Manager offers (TV, phone, tablet, automotive and wear OS) and I realized that the value of size.width is always the real value divided in two, some examples :

- If the device has a width of 1000, size.width takes the value of 500.
- If the device has a width of 2560, size.width takes the value of 1280.
- etc., always the same result.

I have considered multiplying the size.width value by two (to get the actual value), but in the web browser the size.witdh value is correct so the problem is only on emulated android devices.

Can anyone have any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio to get the width in physical pixels.

Documentation : Logical pixels are roughly the same visual size across devices. Physical pixels are the size of the actual hardware pixels on the device. The number of physical pixels per logical pixel is described by the devicePixelRatio.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not matter as long as it has same aspect ratio. For example, you want to create a Container with height: 1/3 of your screen height, it will look the same whether your screen height is 2560 or 1280, it will look exactly the same.

Comment: Textsize you will calculate based on aspect ratio too?